# Anyone can recommend a select option that includes a search box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frameworks

I have to create a field where I will be able to select between 200-300 options and I would like to have a search box to facilitate the navigation in my select option.

Any recommendation?

Comment: `frameworks` is quite a board tag; are you using any libraries at the moment? jQuery UI autocomplete can do this for you (as will 1,000,000 other jQuery plugins; http://plugins.jquery.com).

Comment: [what SO is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562)

Comment: Yes, I'm using JQuery among other javascript libraries. "frameworks" is not the best tag I guess. I think JQuery autocomplete will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) with [local source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source)

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] });
```